# How do you transform a Derivative to a Recurrence Equation?

Tags: derivatives, recurrence-relations, logistic-regression

In the logistic equation, they say  $\frac{dx}{dt} = rx(1-x)$ is equal to $x_{n+1} = rx_{n}(1-x_{n})$. How do they do that? And if you were to transform $\frac{dx}{dt} = 2$ to the recurrence equation, how does it turn out?

P.S. My math skill is the level of high school math.

Comment: The logistic map is not obtained by discretizing the logistic differential equation. You can get something close by replacing $\dot{x}$ by $(x_{n+1}-x_n)/T$ and $x$ by $x_n$ where $T>0$.

Comment: @KBS But they just turned that into that discretized one. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html
Here's the link. My concern is not the logistic map itself, I just want to know how they transformed it.

Comment: It is a replacement, not a conversion.

Comment: @KBS How did they replace it, on what kind of base? What would dx/dt=2 turn out into, if you replace it as they did?

Comment: mathworld does **not** say the differential equation and the recurrence are "equal". It doesn't talk about the differential equation at all, only using it in a misguided effort to motivate the recurrence.

Comment: @user800956 They replaced it in the same way you would replace a glass by a shoe. You take the glass and put the shoe there. It is nowhere near said there that they transformed the differential equation into a difference equation using a mathematical procedure. It is quite clumsy from them to start with the differential equation. They should have started straight from the logistic map.

Comment: @KBS Could you check if my interpretation is correct then? Here: The logistic differential equation and the logistic sequence are two different things. But the basic idea and assumption are same, so the former comes out like $\frac{dx}{dt} = rx(1-x)$, and the latter comes out like $x_{n+1} = rx_{n}(1-x_{n})$ just because they represent the same idea, not because they are related with each other.

Comment: No, they do not represent the same idea. They just look similar, that's it. Their behavior is really really really different.